# No database connection with no errors

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php-7, ubuntu-16.10

I have Ubuntu 16.10 x86_64 x86_64. I installed LAMP to program in PHP and to create databases. In my php program I want to connect to my local database for creating a table ( in HTML ) with the data of any row of the table.
The problem is that when I open the php file( localhost/file.php ) through firefox ,the browser doesn't charge anything. If thare were been an error during the connection with the database, It would have printed something in the browser. 
Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head><title> SQL & PHP </title></head>

<body>

<?php


$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password")
        or die ("Non riesco a creare la connessione");


mysql_select_db("scuola")
         or die ("Non trovo il DB");

$sql = "SELECT id_utente, nome_utente, password_utente, conta_pres FROM  utenti WHERE conta_pres <> 0";

$ris = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query fallita!");

echo "<TABLE><TR><TH>ID utente <TH> Nome utente <TH>Password<TH>Contatore visite</TR>";

while ($riga= mysql_fetch_array($ris))
{
        echo ("<TR>");
        echo "<TD>"  . $riga["id_utente"];
        echo "<TD>"  . $riga["nome_utente"];
        echo "<TD>"  . $riga["password_utente"];
        echo "<TD>"  . $riga["conta_pres"];

}

mysql_close();
?>
</body>

</html>
```

I checked the syntax (using a website) of  the code and thare aren't problems,even because I copied this one by a book. I read that mysql_connect has been deprecated, so I replaced it with new mysqli_connect but the error still remains: white page. I tried to put 2 echo, one before the connecting function and one after that.  Only the first echo is printed on the screen. I tried to type in the terminal sudo apt-get install php5-mysql   but there is an  error: 
**The "php5-mysql" packet  has not run to install**

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Do not use the mysql_* functions. mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: If you're getting a straight white page, then check your server error logs for the reason.

Comment: I think mysql_connect is deprecated past 5.6. So its likely not even a thing in php-7

Comment: have you installed mysql? you need install mysql first then mysql package to php

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: Don't use E_ALL, set error reporting to -1 instead, it logs even more.

Comment: @delboy1978uk ... I'm pretty sure that, as of PHP 5.4, `E_ALL` and `-1` are the same.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I just saw mysql_ancient_command() and instantly assumed he was on some creakingly ancient PHP :-P

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`.

I think I have found the problem. When you call `mysqli_select_db`, it expects 2 parameters and you only specified one. Even though you have set the `$db` database connection, you need to specify which database you want to select the database name from.

So `mysqli_select_db($db, "scuola")` should do the trick.

And at the bottom close the connection specifying which connection to close. In your case it is: `mysqli_close($db);`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head><title> SQL & PHP </title></head>

    <body>

        <?php


        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password")
            or die ("Non riesco a creare la connessione");


        mysqli_select_db($db, "scuola") // see this line
            or die ("Non trovo il DB");

        $sql = "SELECT id_utente, nome_utente, password_utente, conta_pres FROM  utenti WHERE conta_pres <> 0";

        $ris = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query fallita!");

        echo "<TABLE><TR><TH>ID utente <TH> Nome utente <TH>Password<TH>Contatore visite</TR>";

        while ($riga= mysql_fetch_array($ris))
        {
            echo ("<TR>");
            echo "<TD>"  . $riga["id_utente"];
            echo "<TD>"  . $riga["nome_utente"];
            echo "<TD>"  . $riga["password_utente"];
            echo "<TD>"  . $riga["conta_pres"];

        }

        mysqli_close($db); // see this line
        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```